# OBIEE(11g) mobile - hosting on a separate server

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I am quite new to oracle BI, since my organization needs to provide access to the OBIEE(11g) via internet by the iPad mobile app, we need to provide a separate server only for mobile app and the mobile server should stand inside a DMZ, while OBIEE app remains locally, is it possible to deploy mobile server in a separate server with allowing access to the public? If yes: how? And if no: what are the other ways of approaching this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you access Oracle BI from a mobile device, you are directly accessing the remote server through a client application (the iPad app) on the presentation server host and port.

The problem is that is not a "mobile" server: imagine the client app it's like a Rich Internet Application, something like a dynamic site.

If you can "see" the server from the iPad then that's it.

From what I know OBIEE 11g is installed as a whole package as a weblogic server, so the components cannot be separated.

But, I think you can put a proxy between your iPad and the OBIEE presentation server, like this:

LAN         | DMZ   | WAN
OBIEE 11g   | Proxy | Users (iPad)

This way probably you can limit access to the OBIEE Presentation Server just through the needed port and with augmented security, but always remember the application is one and the server is one!

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT expose either the Presentation server or any other part of OBIEE in your public DMZ. OBIEE can be separated for Enterprise Deployment. You want to create a Virtual IP and put Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) with Webgate (that's Oracle's plugin for the webserver) in a public DMZ which the mobile and other devices can access. Put the rest of OBIEE deployment inside a private DMZ. Refer to the following diagram from [OBIEE Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e15722/intro.htm#CEGIBGFG).

[image]